# prove that a closed ball in Euclidean space is perfect

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I've just been working with just the complex numbers z less than or equal to 1, but am curious as to how one would prove this for all closed balls in Rn as well. I only have up to Rudin page $33$ in my toolkit right now.

I already proved they are closed for my example, but I can't think of an argument to show that every point is a limit point.

Comment: is a single point to be considered a closed ball of radius $0$?

Comment: No, r>0. The set containing a single point has no limit points and therefore is closed but not perfect according to rudin's definitions.

Answer (score 1):

If $c$ is the center of the ball and if $p$ belongs to the ball, then$$p=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)p+\frac1nc=p,$$and each $\left(1-\frac1n\right)p+\frac1nc$ belongs to the closed ball, since it is a point from the line segment joining $c$ to $p$.

Comment: The center itself is the limit of $(1+\frac 1 n) c$ so it is a limit point if $c \neq 0$. If $c=0$ we can look at $(\frac 1 n)$

Comment: We haven't defined limits yet in Rudin, but I see that this clearly proves it.